# Does the following statement make sense?

Tags: past-tense

"As I answered the questions, I realized that those who devoted their lives to create change are forever remembered."

Or should it be:

"As I answered the questions, I realized that those who devote their lives to create change are forever remembered."

In context, the answers to the questions are people like Marie Curie or Adam Smith – people who "devoted their lives to create change."

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically valid. As for their content: you're asking other people to read your mind, which is impossible – especially with such minimal context.

Comment: “What economist first introduced the concept of ‘the invisible hand’?” asked my friend as he looked at his phone. 
During our biweekly coffee gatherings at the local Starbucks, a small group of friends and I enjoy testing each other’s knowledge on miscellaneous subjects. For a few seconds, my heart paces as I search through my mind’s filing cabinets for an answer. This thrill keeps me alive –it inspires me to do something meaningful with my life.

Comment: This is the context btw :) I appreciate your willingness to help

Answer (score 2):

If you want the realisation you speak of to be construed as a maxim or general principle, then 'devote' is better.

If you want to speak only of a set of specific people who have devoted their lives to change, then 'devoted' is better. Incidentally, in this case I would suggest 'will be forever remembered' as opposed to 'are forever remembered' since this is a statement about the future (clearly, they have been remembered thus far since we are talking about them).

I take it from the comment ("people 'like' Marie Curie...") that you are talking in general and that you expect this principle to continue to be true, so I would suggest 'devote'.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with shai's answer. I would add that using "devoted" in past tense should be done only if all the people you are referring to are dead. Use "devote" to include living and/or yet-to-be-born changemakers.

Answer (score -2):

Try: *As I answered, a thought came upon me. All remember those who have devoted their lives to change.*

Try: *As I spoke the names — Curie, Smith — thought flashed before me. Those who devote their lives to causing change are the ones who get remembered.*

Try: *As I answered, an insight came upon me. All remember those who have devoted their lives to change.*

---

Saying or writing, *"As I answered the questions"* reveals redundancy. Answering means replying to questions. There is no reason to add the redundant phrase, *the questions* to the phrase, *as I answered*.

You can't *"create change"*. You can cause change though. Change is an effect. It must have a cause.

You can create life. You can create things. Creating is realizing — bringing forth into matter.

Change is abstraction. It's a moment in time in which action heads elsewhere. You cannot create time.

Comment: Downvoted? LOLZ. Stack Exchangers are such nerds.